Accessing nested field in painless script
I have a nested field in my mapping called order_details. I want to perform some logic on the order details. for that i am using a painless script. before performing the logic i am checking if the field exist but i get no results when using contains key on nested field.
My Mapping
{
"order_details": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "attachment_ref": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "item": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "description": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
               
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
               
              }
            },
            "product_image_key": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "globalid": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "quote": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "thumbnail_key": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "title": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "type": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },}

Below is my query:
{
  "query": {
   "bool": {
     "filter": [
       {
         "script": {
           "script": {
             "source": """
             if (doc.containsKey('order_details')){
               return true;
             }
             else{
               return false;
             }
             """,
             "lang": "painless"
           }
         }
       }
     ]
   }
  }
}

The above query doesnot return any document although i have documents with nested field.
What is the behavior of nested field?

You need to add your script inside a nested query. This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67898093/4604579

Tried that as well but does not return any document.

Can you update your question with the actually query your tried and please also include the mapping of the relevant fields

I was looking to return the document whose description has around 200 words. So i was trying to count the number of words using the painless script.

@user3134614, Val suggested in his answer the fast unscripted solution instead of your scripted one. Just test the suggested mapping and query

I would do it differently using the token count field type. Your description field should be defined like this:
        "description": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "length": {
              "type": "token_count",
              "analyzer": "standard"
            },               
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }              
          }
        },

And then the query becomes a simple nested range query over the order_details.description.length field:
{
  "nested": {
    "path": "order_details",
    "query": {
      "range": {
        "order_details.description.length": {
          "gte": 195,
          "lte": 205
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


ok.I will try that but question remains same how can i access the nested field in painless script. Does not the doc has nested fields.

Look at my first comment above, the script needs to be in a nested query. You need to include the query you were trying and that doesn't return anything.

I did that but still i could not get any document. {
"query": {
"bool": {
"filter": [
{
"nested": {
"path": "order_details",
"query": {
"script": {
"script": {
"source": """
if (doc.containsKey('order_details')){
return true;
}
else{
return false;
}
""",
"lang": "painless"
}
}
}
}
}
]
}
}
} Still no docs returned

Change doc.containsKey('order_details')) by the actual field you want to check, i.e. doc.containsKey('order_details.description.keyword')). And just know that you cannot access doc.containsKey('order_details.description')) using doc as it's a text field, so you need to access the keyword field and split it by spaces
